# How to plot a graph from csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib

I have the following code and was wondering how to plot it as a graph in python

```
year,month,sales,expenditure
2018,jan,6226,3808
2018,feb,1521,3373
2018,mar,1842,3965
2018,apr,2051,1098
2018,may,1728,3046
2018,jun,2138,2258
2018,jul,7479,2084
2018,aug,4434,2799
2018,sep,3615,1649
2018,oct,5472,1116
2018,nov,7224,1431
2018,dec,1812,3532
```

this is my code so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('sales.csv','r') as sales_csv:
    plots = csv.reader(sales_csv, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[3])

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline  # jupyter notebook


# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(6.8, 4.2))
x = range(len(data['month']))
plt.plot(x, data['sales'])
plt.xticks(x, data['month'])
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.show()
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
df =pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=',')

months = {'jan':1,
          'feb':2,
          'mar':3,
          'apr':4,
          'may':5,
          'jun':6,
          'jul':7,
          'aug':8,
          'sep':9,
          'oct':10,
          'nov':11,
          'dec':12
         }

plt.plot(df['month'].replace(months), df['sales'], label='sales')
plt.plot(df['month'].replace(months), df['expenditure'], label='expenditure')

plt.gca().set_xticks(list(months.values()))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(list(months.keys()))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: What would the entire code look like? The above doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: what does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No worries - I worked it out! I didn't include the file name in - Thank you for your help!!